# NSDictionary representing Inbox Message Structure

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, cordova

What is the structure of the NSDictionaries representing Inbox messages that  are returned in an Array by `sfmc_getAllMessages`? I'm trying to access the objects in each NSDictionary and need to know what the keys are.

In `v4` of the SDK, the old equivalent to `getAllMessages` returns messages of the `ETMessage` class, which has documented properties and methods. I haven't been able to find the documentation for v6.

The current [documentation](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledoc/Classes/MarketingCloudSDK.html#//api/name/sfmc_getAllMessages) simply states this about what `sfmc_getAllMessages` returns:

```
Return Value:
array of NSDictionaries representing Inbox messages
```

Is there a place where the structure of the NSDictionaries is documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through testing, I was able to log the following NSDictionary structure for Inbox each message in the NSArray:

```
{
     alert = Test;
     contentType = 2;
     endDateUtc = "2019-04-25 16:49:00 +0000";
     id = some-ID-here;
     messageDeleted = 0;
     messageHash = "MESSAGE-HASH-HEREO/O1234AASD";
     name = "Test 3/25";
     read = 0;
     sound = default;
     startDateUtc = "2019-03-25 15:50:00 +0000";
     statusDirty = 0;
     subject = "Inbox Test";
     subtitle = Test;
     title = "3/25";
     url = "https://url-to-message-here.com/abcdefg1234/";
 }
```

You can then access those values using NSDictionary's `valueForKey`

Comment: I still think this should be added to the documentation somewhere...

Comment: How are you able to log NSDictionary structure for Inbox  message. I tried adding print but couldn't see them in device logs.